# PHP How to calculate duplicate values in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I would like to calculate duplicate values in my array by "groupid":

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1230
            [groupid] => 177
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => First name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1231
            [groupid] => 177
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => Second name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1232
            [groupid] => 178
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => Other name
        )

)
```

Output array (2 groupid = 177 and 1 groupid = 178):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1231
            [groupid] => 177
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => Second name
            [count] => 2

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1232
            [groupid] => 178
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => Other name
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Um..calculate? what kind of calculation, and on what fields? Please be more specific

Comment: There seems to be some data-loss in your example: Only 1 `id` value and 1 `name` value is kept when the 2 arrays with identical groupids are grouped. Is that on purpose?

Comment: It's right example. Just calculate groupids count and remove duplicate.

Comment: If it happens that your array is populated by a SQL query, please do this from the query, not with some PHP code.

Comment: This is my query: $sql = 'SELECT wall.id, members.groupid, last.activity_group_last, groups.name FROM `#__community_wall` AS wall, `#__community_groups_members` AS members, `#__mod_table` AS last, `#__community_groups` AS groups WHERE members.memberid ='.intval($uid).' AND members.approved = 1 AND members.groupid = wall.contentid AND wall.post_by !='.intval($uid).' AND wall.type="groups" AND wall.id > last.activity_group_last AND last.userid ='.intval($uid).' AND last.activity_group_last > 0 AND last.activity_group_last_new = "0" AND groups.id = members.groupid ORDER BY wall.id';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $value contains your array, then:

```
$count = array_count_values(array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['groupid'];
}, $value));
var_dump($count);

$_tmp = $count;
$unique = array_filter($value, function(&$item) use (&$_tmp, $count) {
    if (!--$_tmp[$item['groupid']]) {
        $item['count'] = $count[$item['groupid']];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
var_dump($unique);
```

results in:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1231)
    ["groupid"]=>
    int(177)
    ["activity_group_last"]=>
    int(1229)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Second name"
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1232)
    ["groupid"]=>
    int(178)
    ["activity_group_last"]=>
    int(1229)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Other name"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but you could add some comments, unless you aspire for the "Most Obscure Code Snippet of the Day" -award ;-)

Comment: But I need to add: [count] => X to output array

Comment: Yes my friend, you are the rock!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using an iterative function.  If your input array is stored in $input and you want the results in $output:

```
function remove_duplicates($input_array) {
  $output_array = array();            // Create an empty array for output
  foreach($input_array as $input) {   // Loop the input array
    if(array_key_exists($input['groupid'], $output_array)) {
      // We've already seen this groupid at least once
      // Increment count
      $input['count'] = $output_array[$input['groupid']]['count'] + 1;
    } else {
      // First time we've seen this groupid
      // Set count to 1
      $input['count'] = 1;
    }
    // Store data in $output_array, indexed by group_id
    $output_array[$input['groupid']] = $input;
  }
}

// This is your input array
$input = array(array('id'=>1230,'groupid'=>177,'activity_group_last'=>1229,'name'=>'First name'),
           array('id'=>1231,'groupid'=>177,'activity_group_last'=>1229,'name'=>'Second name'),
           array('id'=>1232,'groupid'=>178,'activity_group_last'=>1229,'name'=>'Other name'));
// This will set the output array correctly
$output = remove_duplicates($input);
```

Comment: The is a problem with this function. It output: Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1279
            [groupid] => 177
            [activity_group_last] => 1275
            [name] => Name
            [count] => 4
        )

)
But we have other array (input):
[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1232
            [groupid] => 178
            [activity_group_last] => 1229
            [name] => Other name
        )

Comment: The is a problem with this function. It output: Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1279
            [groupid] => 177
            [activity_group_last] => 1275
            [name] => Name
            [count] => 4
        )

)

Comment: Script is updated to set $input to the values you originally provided;  in a quick test, it works fine.  Can you be more specific with the problem you're seeing?